# Azure CLI (PS) | az storage blob generate-sas | Https connection failure

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am **using the Azure CLI** to create a **blob level user delegated SAS**, using steps from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli).

I have hidden the name of my storage account for the purpose of this post.

The PowerShell `az storage blob generate-sas` cmdlet is returning;

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with
>   url:
>   //storeageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net?restype=service&comp=userdelegationkey
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2]
>   Name or service not known',))

and I noticed that the URL = *//storeageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net*, and not, *https://storeageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net*.

The PowerShell code:

```
$sasToken = az storage blob generate-sas `
    --account-name $storageAccount `
    --container-name $container `
    --name $blob `
    --permissions acdrw `
    --expiry "2020-04-10T14:50Z" `
    --auth-mode login `
    --as-user `
    --full-uri
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure CLI mode **was** set to **classic** and **not** set to **ARM**.

1. Ran `azure config mode arm`.
2. Executed `az storage blob generate-sas` again and SAS was returned.

Comment: huh, it has classic mode, what?

Comment: why are you setting old cli to arm mode and what does this have to do with az cli?